# How can Vuforia targets be created from a device database at runtime on separate thread?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

The documentation [here](https://library.vuforia.com/unity-extension/create-and-load-targets-unity#create-multiple-targets-from-a-device-database-at-runtime) on the Vuforia website shows how multiple targets can be created from a device database using a set of hardcoded target names and recommends creating many targets on a separate thread and coroutine. However, it does not show how to do that and there might be several issues with those recommendations.

- There are async versions of creating individual targets, but not one for creating all targets from a database. This has me concerned that for a large database creating individual targets async will end up loading the database from disk multiple times.
- Creating multiple individual targets asynchronously requires knowing all the target names beforehand, which would require us to extract those names from a database ahead of time (custom coding as build step or loading and parsing a device database separate from Vuforia at runtime).
- Unity Monobehaviours can only be created on the main thread, so it should not possible to do this on a separate thread (perhaps this is referring to using the Async versions of the Vuforia create target methods which might do non-Unity work on a background thread, but create Unity objects on main thread). Coroutines would be helpful to use with the individual async methods, but again this raises concerns this will cause other performance issues with loading a large device database from disk multiple times.

How do developers generally handle loading large numbers of targets from a device database with these issues in mind?